# How to fetch patterns from a game board in a fast way?

Tags: c++, performance, pattern-matching

For my recent project I'm right now looking for an efficient way to structure and store the board information with consideration of the usage for patternmatching.

I'm having a square board, and for pattern matching, I'm using bitfields with 2 bits representing one field of the board. The patterns to match have a diamond shape, that could be centered around any possible field on the board. (so the center is not static, I need to be able to do it for any center)

Example of diamond area around O:

```
..X..
.XXX.
XXOXX
.XXX.
..X..
```

If parts of the diamond are outside the the playing area, the bits will be set to 11. The diamonds can have differing radiuses, aboves example would have a radius of 2.
Another important thing for the efficiency of the system is, that I have to be able to quickly rotate/mirror the pattern into all 8 possible symmetries.
For this, it may be beneficial to actually NOT store the information of the central point in the pattern, and as this is not required for my algorithm anyway, this may be a valuable timesaver. Because now some bitshifting magic is possible to quickly rotate/mirror the patterns.

As this kind of patternmatching has to be done at a high frequency, it can prove to be a severe bottleneck of my overall project, when implemented badly. 
When trying to get a nice model for doing all this work, I figured, there are 3 important keyareas that require thinking about, but are of course tightly connected.

A. How is the data stored in the board implementation.

Currently this is done in a rather difficult manner, which would be too difficult to read from with such high frequency. But it would be no problem or timeloss to actually store and update the 2 bit data in any possible way for the entire board. 
Easiest would be to just store the entire board in an bitset with the size of twice the board, and then each two bit represent the value of a single field. But there is no necessarity for doing it in a special sequence or in only one bitset, even though at first it may look natural to do so. 
Anyway, this is the part I'm most felxible about, as this can be done without performance issues in any way it seves the other 2 critical parts of the problem the best.

B. How is the data stored in the pattern.

This is already more difficult. As said, my intention is to store them in a bitset of the appropriate size, but there is he question in what order.
There seem to be two ways, that quickly come to mind:

a) (this could be done with or without the central point C)

```
...0...
..123..
.45678.
9ABCDEF
.GHIJK.
..LMN..
...O...
```

b)

```
...0...
..N14..
.ML235.
KJI.678
.HFC9A.
..GDB..
...E...
```

If we are just talking about the patterns, b) seems clearly superior. A rotation of the pattern is done by a simple rotateshift (3 bitops total per rotation) and even mirroring the pattern can be done with about a dozen bitops. This kind of operations are much more time consuming with a).
But b) has also some severe drawback... And this leads to:

C. How is the data read from the board implementation to the pattern.

Looking at aboves 2 potential ways to order the pattern bits, now a) is clearly superior. a) can be read by a bunch of bitops from a potential array, as discussed in A. you bitshift each line (getting the line by AND with a bitset nulling all other bits) to the appropriate place and put them together with some OR-operations. Even near the board edges this is done very quick.
Problem of course is, that this would still only get me one possible symmetry of the pattern, but rotations/mirrors are not that easily done. This could be circumvented by saving each pattern to match agaisnt 8 times, but this would look very crude, and may cause troubles elsewhere.
With b) this is much more difficult... Honestly, I don't see a way how it can be done quick, without checking every single bit individually. But when increasing the pattern size (like radius 15) this takes forever, when done very often, especially as the [] operator of bitsets is rather slow.
One possible solution I thought of writing it in CUDA, with each thread generating a pattern around one field, and each block of the thread checking one fixed position around this center. But as I haven't used CUDA before, I don't know how reasonable this is, but if done parallel, this sounds more reasonable than iterating over all positions serially.

As I still didn't find a satisfying solution for the problem, I wanted to ask here, if someone probably knows how it can be done better:
- either rotate/mirror patterns of type a)
- or quickly read pattern of type b) (possibly by arranging the data in a better way in step A., I'm flexible here)
- or if the CUDA idea may actually solve that problem
- or maybe some completely different way, I didn't think of, as I'm sure this has been done before by smarter people

If it matters: I'm coding with VS Pro 2013 and don't mind using boost. If CUDA could solve this effectively, I would also use it.

EDIT:
Okay... So I continued thinking about the whole thing. Maybe there are some other ways to make the whole thing more efficient, by doing some work in more efficient batches.
First of all, what I usually need: On a given board position (and we are talking about 10k positions per second) I need for a large set of positions (every empty field of the board, so most fields) all patterns from size 15 down to size 3. I only need the biggest pattern matched by my database, but in any case, I may often need most of them. So there are 2 things, that could make some time savings possible:

1) some efficient way to use the larger pattern, to generate the pattern one size smaller. This should actually possible, when using the bitordering from b), if it is done the proper way... Then it would only need a few bit ops to cut out the outer ring...
2) As often neighboring fields need their specific pattern, if there would be some way to create their patterns in some sort of batch operation... But I admit, I don't see how this could be done very well... But there may be some time savings.

Oh, and another additional comment, as I had the discussion earlier today with some friend: No it is not an option, t instead of matching the board position against the pattern database, to reverse it and do it the other way around (check if DB pattern matches some board position) I have way too many patterns for that. When doing it the first way, i can just look, if the bitstring exists in my database and be done.

Edit2:
Another Update... First I looked into CUDA, and as it seems incompatible with VS2013, this is a severe blow to that idea. Second I thought about the process how patterns are matched. In fact, it may seem possible, instead of going from the large patterns down to the small ones, doing it in reverse. Now suddenly my pattern library is less of a dictionary but more of a searchtree, as larger patterns certainly have their inner core saved as pattern as well. This should speed up any lookups, but still does not solve my problem of the patterngeneration, sadly.

Edit3:
As I felt, it is more worth of an answer then an edit, I just posted my own new idea (which is different from what I had in mind when posting this question) below.

Comment: What are you actually *doing* with the data? Generally when performing windowed functions on a large array you can reuse information from the previous row/column for the current one, and this will likely provide a larger win than just reshuffling your data structures.

Comment: @moonshadow I intend to build a database of 'known' board positions from some eternal knowledge (those patterns are harvested by another program) and give those some evaluation. So now my game engine, as part of a Monte Carlo Tree Search bot can look up those evaluations, if it encounters those positions. Well... And for hat I have at first to check for every possible move, if there is a possible patternmatch centered on it. But if you could enlighten me on how to effectively reuse that data, this would probably also really help me.

Comment: So, wait, you have a database of little diamond-shaped bits of board and you're trying to find the largest one that matches some part of the current board position? Am I getting that right?

Comment: @moonshadow almost correct -

for every empty intersection on the board I want to know the largest pattern centered around that intersection. As the patterns contain an evaluation value, I will use this value to evaluate which possible move may be the best next.
So I need the biggest pattern for each empty intersection, not only the biggest for the entire board

Comment: Some kind of Go AI? This sounds like it will be a very expensive operation to do just by forming a key for each rotation/reflection of each diamond size for each empty intersection and looking for an exact match in a database. You need a cheap operation on the whole board giving a rotation invariant result that lets you prune search space before performing expensive lookups/tests; perhaps calculate a population count around each intersection (a cheap GPU-friendly convolution) and keep a list of best possible evaluation values per population so you can skip checking the poor ones?

Comment: There's a lot of research into solving this kind of problem for the purposes of image matching / OCR, that may be worth looking into; suitable search terms are subimage search, subimage crosscorrelation, image template search etc

Comment: yes, it is a Go AI. And I will try to check those searchterms you mentioned. 
And yes, it is incredibly expensive for me right now, that's why I'm lookking for improvements and ideas ^^

Comment: @moonshadow Okay, I checked out what I could find on sub image search /crosscorrelation etc. But to me it feels like those keywords are more about finding a low number of patterns in a large image. But this isn't the case here. Here we are talking about a 7 digit number of patterns to be possibly found, on a rather small image (19x19x2 bits, if you add some 15 field radius around it, it would still be only 39x39x2 bits) And, as I said, I actually need the patternatch for each possible center of the pattern. But I will prepare another edit with some more ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as I was thinking about this more and more, I now think, that the following solution may be the best to tackle the problems. This is certainly not final, but my currently best idea. So any criticism is welcome and improvements can surely be made.

As the discussion in the comments led me to the believe, that the approach imagined in the question is not practical for the problem at hand, I now drastically changed my idea. Instead of trying to read the pattern around each empty intersection after each move, I will now update the surrounding pattern of each empty intersection after each move made. 
This can be made in an efficient way, as we can use 2 very important features of our patterns:

1) each larger patterns core (so the pattern reduced to a lower radius) will guaranteed to be in the database

2) most patterns will have a rather low radius, and in most cases, not many positions on the board are changed with each move, resulting in not too many positions needing a recheck of their patterns.

My idea is, to store the currently largest pattern, it's radius and it's evaluation with each empty intersection. Now, while a move is made, I generate a list of all positions changed during that move. (usually one) Once the move is finished, I iterate over all empty positions on the board and look at their distance to the closest change. Now we are having 3 possible cases:

a) the distance is smaller or equal the radius of currently matched pattern. Now we have to recheck the pattern.

b) the distance is one bigger then the radius of the currently matched pattern. Now we have to check, if actually a (r+1) size pattern exists, matching the surrounding. If it does, we have to check r+2 etc, until we found the largest.

c) the distance is even bigger: We can keep everything as it is.

As we are having now basically a tree of patterns, with each pattern having lots of child pattern with an incremented radius, it is actually practical to store the pattern information in a series of bitets, each representing a ring of a certain radius around the center.

I hope that this system maximizes the reusability of all the information at hand and is fast enough for my needs. As mentioned before, I welcome criticism and opinions for improvement and if there is not better solution found, will probably implement it in the near future. Once done, I can probably report back on the results.